# web3.exceptions.BadFunctionCallOutput: Could not decode contract function call getEvidence return data b'' for output_types ['string']

Tags: blockchain, dapps, private

Solidity Code:

```
function getEvidence(string memory _evidenceID) view public returns (string memory) {
        require(evidenceOwner[_evidenceID] == msg.sender);
        string memory evidenceHash = evidenceIpfsHash[_evidenceID];
        return evidenceHash;
    }
```

Python Code:

```py
@app.route('/getevi.html', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def getevi():
    form = SignUpForm()
    if form.is_submitted():
        #web3.geth.personal.unlockAccount('0xe22858f99220ba98adc9be20558a75a323ec4749', 'redhat')
        evidenceID = request.form['eid']
        print(evidenceID)
        file_info = bcoc.functions.getEvidence(evidenceID).call()
        print(file_info)
        return render_template('getevi.html', file_info=file_info)  
    return render_template('getevi.html', form=form)
```

Output:

```
[2019-09-23 12:01:23,688] ERROR in app: Exception on /getevi.html [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mahir/test123/testDapp/microVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/contract.py", line 1354, in call_contract_function
    output_data = decode_abi(output_types, return_data)
  File "/home/mahir/test123/testDapp/microVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eth_abi/codec.py", line 179, in decode_abi
    return decoder(stream)
  File "/home/mahir/test123/testDapp/microVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eth_abi/decoding.py", line 127, in __call__
    return self.decode(stream)
  File "/home/mahir/test123/testDapp/microVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eth_utils/functional.py", line 45, in inner
    return callback(fn(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/mahir/test123/testDapp/microVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eth_abi/decoding.py", line 173, in decode
    yield decoder(stream)
  File "/home/mahir/test123/testDapp/microVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eth_abi/decoding.py", line 127, in __call__
    return self.decode(stream)
  File "/home/mahir/test123/testDapp/microVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eth_abi/decoding.py", line 142, in decode
    start_pos = decode_uint_256(stream)
  File "/home/mahir/test123/testDapp/microVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eth_abi/decoding.py", line 127, in __call__
    return self.decode(stream)
  File "/home/mahir/test123/testDapp/microVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eth_abi/decoding.py", line 198, in decode
    raw_data = self.read_data_from_stream(stream)
  File "/home/mahir/test123/testDapp/microVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eth_abi/decoding.py", line 308, in read_data_from_stream
    len(data),
eth_abi.exceptions.InsufficientDataBytes: Tried to read 32 bytes.  Only got 0 bytes

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mahir/test123/testDapp/microVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/mahir/test123/testDapp/microVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/mahir/test123/testDapp/microVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/mahir/test123/testDapp/microVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/mahir/test123/testDapp/microVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/mahir/test123/testDapp/microVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "app.py", line 215, in getevi
    file_info = bcoc.functions.getEvidence(evidenceID).call()
  File "/home/mahir/test123/testDapp/microVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/contract.py", line 842, in call
    **self.kwargs
  File "/home/mahir/test123/testDapp/microVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/web3/contract.py", line 1376, in call_contract_function
    raise BadFunctionCallOutput(msg) from e
web3.exceptions.BadFunctionCallOutput: Could not decode contract function call getEvidence return data b'' for output_types ['string']
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Sep/2019 12:01:23] "POST /getevi.html HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Comment: Do you still get an error if you comment out the `require` in your function?

Comment: yes... I am able to send a transaction into the network but i am unable to get it from the network... Is there any specific command to get string output? i have tried .call() method

Comment: Then that code is probably not running at the address you're calling. Double check the address for `bcoc` and the network that you're connected to. Make sure it matches what you deployed.

Comment: I checked the address still its showing same error. Is there any alternative of calling .call() function which I can use?

Comment: No, `call()` is correct.

Comment: Did you find a Solution? Same error here.